# How to allow Facebook User choose account to Log In with

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

As part of business requirements, when a user wants to log into my app via Facebook, if he has multiple facebook accounts that he's currently logged into, I want to give him the opportunity to choose from any of them.

I felt that the usual way that has been implemented in oauth is by using the `prompt` key but Facebook is not bringing up any dialog when I add `prompt` so the user can choose his preferred account.

Facebook keeps picking the first account. Below is my code:

```
window.FB.login(function (response) {
    let { status, authResponse } = response;
    if (!authResponse) {
        //Throw error
    } else {
        if (status === "connected") {
            //Move On
        } else {
            //Throw error
        }
    }
}, {
    scope: facebookLoginScopes.join(","),
    prompt: 'consent',     //I thought this is meant to pull up a choice dialog of accounts?
    return_scopes: true,
});
```

Please how can I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Users are only allowed to have one Facebook account.